# Nested table in email android gmail app

Tags: android, css, email, gmail, nested-table

Ive done a html page to be used in an email. This has a nested table in which works fine in desktop browsers and email applications

But when viewed in the gmail android app the width of the nested table decreases by 2px. Can anyone tell me why this happening? Please find the code below or in this [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/DanPacey/32nx0srq/)

```
    <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <tr>
            <td width ="600" height="236">
                <a href="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/" >
                    <img src="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/eshots/new-year-eshot/images/nova-ny_01.jpg" width="600" height="236" style="display: block;"/>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width ="600" height="207">
                <a href="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/acatalog/diet.html" >
                    <img src="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/eshots/new-year-eshot/images/nova-ny_02.jpg" width="600" height="207" style="display: block;"/>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width ="600" height="195">
                <a href="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/acatalog/diet.html" >
                    <img src="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/eshots/new-year-eshot/images/nova-ny_03.jpg" width="600" height="195" style="display: block;" />
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="600" height="147">
                <table id="products"width="600" height="147" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; display: block;">
                    <tr>
                        <td width ="37" height="147" >
                            <a href="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/acatalog/diet.html" >
                                <img src="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/eshots/new-year-eshot/images/nova-ny_04.jpg" width="37" height="147" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td width ="117" height="147" >
                            <a href="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/cgi-bin/sh000002.cgi?WD=fat%20thermogenic%20burner&PN=natural-fat-burners-slimming-supplements%2ehtml#a681" >
                                <img src="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/eshots/new-year-eshot/images/nova-ny_05.jpg" width="117" height="147" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td width ="21" height="147" >
                            <a href="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/acatalog/diet.html" >
                                <img src="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/eshots/new-year-eshot/images/nova-ny_06.jpg" width="21" height="147" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td width ="117" height="147" >
                            <a href="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/cgi-bin/sh000002.cgi?WD=dietary%20complex%20fibre&PN=dietary-fibre-supplement%2ehtml#a3011" >
                                <img src="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/eshots/new-year-eshot/images/nova-ny_07.jpg" width="117" height="147" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td width ="21" height="147" >
                            <a href="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/acatalog/diet.html" >
                                <img src="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/eshots/new-year-eshot/images/nova-ny_08.jpg" width="21" height="147" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td width ="117" height="147" >
                            <a href="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/cgi-bin/sh000002.cgi?WD=fat%20blocker%20carb&PN=fat-magnet-diet-pills%2ehtml#a2999" >
                                <img src="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/eshots/new-year-eshot/images/nova-ny_09.jpg" width="117" height="147" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td width ="21" height="147" >
                            <a href="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/acatalog/diet.html" >
                                <img src="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/eshots/new-year-eshot/images/nova-ny_10.jpg" width="21" height="147" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td width ="118" height="147" >
                            <a href="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/cgi-bin/sh000002.cgi?WD=acai%20berry&PN=pure-acia-berry-weight-loss-pills%2ehtml#a813" >
                                <img src="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/eshots/new-year-eshot/images/nova-ny_11.jpg" width="118" height="147" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td width ="31" height="147" >
                            <a href="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/acatalog/diet.html" >
                                <img src="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/eshots/new-year-eshot/images/nova-ny_12.jpg" width="31" height="147" id="last-image"/>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="600" height="102">
                <a href="http://www.novadetox.co.uk" >
                    <img src="http://www.novadetox.co.uk/eshots/new-year-eshot/images/nova-ny_13.jpg" width="600" height="102" style="display: block;" />
                </a>
            </td>
    </table>
```